# Build/Rebuild Project VS 2008 using DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, build, rebuild, envdte

How can I Build and Rebuild a Project csproj using DTE.ExecuteCommand ?

Any reference of all commands of DTE ?

For solution, I use this:

```
 Logica.BuildTracking.IniciarBuildTrack();
                    proyecto.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.RebuildSolution", "");
                    while (!Logica.BuildTracking.BuildFinalizado)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
```

I try use this:

```
 // TODO !!!
                    proyecto.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.BuildOnlyProject", "");
```

but I get error: "Command \"Build.BuildOnlyProject\" is not available."

Comment: Was my answer helpful at all?

Comment: not all mister terrance, I need get project using name of solution and project.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get started

```
//gets build obj
var sb = proyecto.DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild;
//sets the object to build; still figuring out what can be done with this one...
sb.SolutionConfigurations.Item(1).Activate();
//optional arg for if you want to wait for the build to finish
sb.Build(true);
```

I'm still playing with the method you were using ExecuteCommand but you can use the default param and write it like this:

`proyecto.DTE.ExecuteCommand("SomeCommand");`

because the second parameter is set by default to an empty string.
For more info take a look at this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa301352%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I need access using name of Project and Solution, not index

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300719%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for the `Build` command in DTE.